# Finding .plist file names and putting them as strings in an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I have an iOS app, written in Objective-C, that uses more than one .plist file for storing information. I need to fetch all the names of said .plist files (for example: in a file called "chicken.plist", I'd like it to get "chicken") and put them in an array for later usage. How could I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by using this code:

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *appFolderPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *fileArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                        directoryContentsAtPath:appFolderPath];
```

It fetches the files from the "Documents" folder. If you need to find the whereabouts of the documents folder for your app in order to monitor its contents for developmental reasons, I used this code:

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *appFolderPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSLog(@"App Directory is: %@", appFolderPath);
NSLog(@"Directory Contents:\n%@", [fileManager directoryContentsAtPath: appFolderPath]);
```

It sends the address of the folder to the log, where you can just copy it, then press cmd+shift+G in Finder, paste it, then press enter to open it.

The code I used is a mixture of code I found in various tutorials online.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad, so I'll give you a very broad answer. Please don't ask me to give you code.

Take a look at the methods in `NSFileManager`. There are methods that let you get an array of the files in a directory.

If these are files in your app bundle, take a look at the NSBundle method `URLsForResourcesWithExtension:subdirectory:'. That might just give you an array of the URLs to your files in 1 call. You'd then query each url object for the path component you wanted.

Comment: What kind of information should I add to make it less broad? I thought I added everything important.

Comment: Do some research yourself. I've given you several things to look into. Go read up, try to work out the code, and update your question with code if you can't get it to work.